# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete

Tags: blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

I'm following the Solana tutorial https://merunasgrincalaitis.medium.com/the-ultimate-solana-step-by-step-guide-including-programs-dapps-and-rust-from-scratch-d3bfb02b5f2e and learing solana and anchor.Now I'm writing the test,but when I inputed `anchor test`, I am prompted for error `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete`.And here's lib.rs and test code:

```rs
// lib.rs
#[program]
pub mod solana_global_article {
  use super::*;
  pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
    // Get the article
    let article_account = &mut ctx.accounts.article;
    // Initialize the variables (this is required)
    article_account.content = ("Story: ").to_string();

    Ok(())
  }
}

#[account]
pub struct Article {
  pub content: String,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
  #[account(
        init,
        payer = authority,
        space = 8 + 32 + 10000 
    )]
  pub article: Account<'info, Article>,
  #[account(mut)]
  pub authority: Signer<'info>,
  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

//test code
it("Is initialized", async () => {
    const deployerKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
    const authority = (program.provider as anchor.AnchorProvider).wallet;

    // Add your test here.
    await program.methods
      .initialize()
      .accounts({
        article: deployerKeypair.publicKey,
        authority: authority.publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      })
      .signers([deployerKeypair])
      .rpc();
  });
```

It took me all night but I didn't get it right. I am hoping someone would help.Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide some more context and the error logs. Based on the initial reading, this is all correct! Be sure that `authority` has enough SOL to create the account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I moved them to a new anchor project and passed.Perhaps some of the settings are wrong.But thankfully it worked.